# Is there any way to kill an activity when its in picture-in-picture mode from another activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I have two Activities **ActivityA** and **ActivityB** (this one has pip mode enabled)
when **ActivityB** is in pip mode,**ActivityA** comes to the foreground now I want to finish/destroy/kill **ActivityB** from **ActivityA** is there any way to do this?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        val supportsPIP = context!!.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE)
       
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (supportsPIP) {
                enterPictureInPictureMode(mPictureInPictureParamsBuilder!!.build())
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: what have to tried so far for killing the activity?

Comment: using LocalBroadcastManager actually solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

After checking this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896347/13373099 I realized that All I had to do was just use **LocalBroadcastManager**
if anyone having trouble implementing this, here is what I did

in **ActivityB**

private val mReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
intent?.let { intent ->
        if (intent.action == "FINISH_ACTIVITY") {
            
            finish(); // finish/kill activity also destroys the pip
            
        }}
}
```

now register the listener

```
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver,  IntentFilter("FINISH_ACTIVITY));
```

in **ActivityA**

just send a broadcast with intent action "FINISH ACTIVITY"

```
 val intent = Intent("FINISH_ACTIVITY")
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way it's to save the reference to the activity in a singleton and when you want to kill it you call `finish()` and the set the reference to null again.